# Zend 2: Add prefix to route's action

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-route

I have application with following URLs

```
www.myapp.com/admin/profile           [index action]
www.myapp.com/admin/profile/add       [add action]
www.myapp.com/admin/profile/edit      [edit action]
www.myapp.com/admin/profile/del       [delete action]
```

These URLs are for users with admin permissions.
Users who do NOT have admin permissions have following URLs

```
www.myapp.com/user/profile           
www.myapp.com/user/profile/add       
www.myapp.com/user/profile/edit      
www.myapp.com/user/profile/del
```

Routes in Zend 2

```
        // admin routes
        'admin' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/admin',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => __NAMESPACE__.'\Controller',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(

                // Profile
                'profile' => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/profile',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controller',
                            'controller' => 'Profile',
                            'action' => 'index'
                        )
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'default' => array(
                            'type' => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '[/:action[/:id]]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                    'id' => '\d+'
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    '__NAMESPACE__' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controller',
                                    'controller' => 'Profile'
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),


        // user routes
        'admin' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/user',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => __NAMESPACE__.'\Controller',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(

                // Profile
                'profile' => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/profile',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controller',
                            'controller' => 'Profile',
                            'action' => 'clientIndex'
                        )
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'default' => array(
                            'type' => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '[/:action[/:id]]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'action' => 'client[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',    <----- look here
                                    'id' => '\d+'
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    '__NAMESPACE__' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controller',
                                    'controller' => 'Profile'
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

What I want to have is that if user access url: www.myapp.com/admin/profile/add
Application run controller **Profile** and action **addAction**

If user access url: www.myapp.com/user/profile/add
Application run controller **Profile** and action **userAddAction**

So I want to add prefix 'user' to every action when **user** routes are used.

I have tried:

```
                      'options' => array(
                            ...
                            'defaults' => array(
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controller',
                                'controller' => 'Profile',
                                'action' => 'user[:action]'     <--- look here
                            )
                        )
```

But of course it doesn't work.

I know I could define static routes, but I would like to do it with Segment routes type

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to *change* the route. Route definitions are there to be *matched* by the URL, so the application is able to execute the correct controller action.

So by defining `'action' => 'client[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'` you are saying that the `[:action]` part of the route *needs to match* on this pattern, which would only happen if you browsed to `www.myapp.com/admin/profile/clientadd` etc.

To resolve your problem you can split your child routes so you have a route per action.

This example shows for the user route, however you can copy this and add them as children of the  `/admin/profile` route also (changing the action value point `addAction` rather than `clientAddAction` etc).

```
// user routes
'user' => [
    // same as before
    'child_routes' => [

        'profile' => [
            // same as before
            'child_routes' => [

                'add' => [
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/add'
                        'defaults' => [
                            // no need for controller value as is
                            // inherited from the 'profile' parent route
                            'action' => 'clientAddAction'
                        ],
                    ],
                ],

                'edit' => [
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/edit/:id',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'action' => 'clientEditAction',
                        ]
                    ],
                ],

                'del' => [
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/del/:id',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'action' => 'clientDeleteAction',
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

The only change you would need to make is when you render a URL within the view.

```
$this->url('/users/profile/default, ['action'=>'add']);
$this->url('/users/profile/default, ['action'=>'edit', 'id' => 123]);
```

Would become.

```
$this->url('/users/profile/add');
$this->url('/users/profile/edit, ['id' => 123]);
```